# Spring: Ho to use a service inside class anotated with @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring, exception

I'm trying to use a service inside a class which is annotated with @ControllerAdvice.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RefreshScope
public class ExceptionHandlerController {
    private final SomeService someService;
...
```

Some Service looks like

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeService extends something{
...
}
```

The exception handler is working fine, as well as the service. But if i try to use the service inside the exception handler iam getting an Exception. The service is null.

Any ideo why this happens on a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice and how to solve this?

Comment: have you tested your code without using lombok? just to be sure the problem is not there?

Comment: Just tried it without the @RequiredArgsConstructor, but exact same behaviour. I have no idea what google for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but most probably your `ExceptionHandlerController` is not a managed spring bean. Meaning you don't have access to `SomeService`. Making your `ExceptionHandlerController` an `@Component` may work, but I'm really not sure...

Comment: I have tried to add @Component sadly it's also not working.

Comment: try debugging and manually coding the constructor with the @Autowire annotation https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: Tried this also, same result. I also implemented an interface for the service, which i used on the excepion handler. Same result. I searched a lot via google and cold not find any hint that this is an issue. But i also did not find a tutorial or something where someone is using a service inside such a class.